# Como voltar à activity e executar um método?

Tags: java, android, dialog

tenho a activity Perfil.class e la exibe minhas fotos, ao clicar nela, abre um fragmentDialog exibindo a foto em slideshow... mas ao deletar a foto, preciso q volte ao meu perfil e atualize as minhas fotos, executando fotos(myID);

Como fazer isso, se possivel?!

SlideshowDialogFragment.class

```
private void delete_photo(final String idPhoto){
        pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getText(R.string.wait));
        showDialog();
        String tag = "deletePhoto";
        pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getText(R.string.wait));
        showDialog();
        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Config.DEL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        new Alert().MessageSuccess(getActivity(), view,
                                getText(R.string.delete_photo_success).toString());
                        // Voltar para meu Perfil.class e executar fotos(myID);


                    } else {
                        new Alert().MessageError(getActivity(), view,
                                getText(R.string.delete_photo_error).toString());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                new Alert().MessageError(getActivity(), view,
                        getText(R.string.error_connection).toString());
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("me", myID);
                params.put("id", idPhoto);
                params.put("token", code);
                return params;
            }
        };
        CustomApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passo a passo:

1 - Crie uma interface a coloque dentro dela um método `void resposta();`
2 - Faça a activity implementar essa interface e programa dentro do método implementado a atualização da lista.
3 - Dentro do fragmento, declare uma variável do tipo da interface.
4 - Na hora de criar o fragmento, envie o this(a activity) e insira esse this na variável da interface que está no fragmento.
5 - Quando terminar o método de exclusão de fotos do fragmento(ou na última linha do método de exclusão), chame interface.resposta();

Esse comando final irá chamar o método `resposta();` da activity(pq dentro a interface conterá o valor this da activity).

Comment: nao entendi o passo 3 e 4... Criei a interface PhotosRefreshMyProfile e no Perfil usei implements PhotosRefreshMyProfile. Tambem no Perfil criei o metodo @Override
    public void resposta() {
        fotos(myID);
    }  esta certo até aqui ?

Comment: consegui, muito obrigado :)